# vscode+java+windows: I want to import and use org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger without Maven

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, log4j

Using only vscode with java extensions added, and native Java 8 without any additional libraries or extensions, I'd like to use log4j.

I have downloaded the various .jar files and they are in my classpath (although classpath is difficult to verify in vscode, would be nice to have an vscode IDE way to verify the actual path your code sees). The files do show up in vscode under the "JAVA DEPENDENCIES" accordion menu on the left EXPLORER.

The 3 primary .jar files are:

- log4j-api-2.11.0.jar
- log4j-core-2.11.0.jar
- log4j-1.2-api-2.11.0.jar

I have a launch.json file with '"windows": {"classPaths":...' defined and a .classpath file added for good measure with the kind="lib" and the fully qualified literal path given to the 3 primary .jar files.

The files are actually in my Windows CLASSPATH variable and shows up when from within this .java code I execute this line of code:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
```

This shows the literal path to the location of three jar files, as well as an entry for ".", and for the folder that they are in as well (likely overkill).

The error I receive from vscode editor is still

```
The import org.apache cannot be resolved
```

in my code's .java file, I have the import, and a red squiggly line is under org.apache

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger
```

Any suggestions of a quick fix that doesn't involve adding Maven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.make sure you hava create a folder named `lib`  and add your `.jar` file into it

2.Configure paths in the `.classpath` like:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/log4j-1.2-api-2.11.2.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/log4j-api-2.11.2.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/log4j-core-2.11.2.jar"/>
```

3.if it still thow error,Clean the workspace directory:

the VS Code user workspace storage area can be found under these locations :

- Windows : %APPDATA%\Code[ - Variant]\User\workspaceStorage\
- MacOS : $HOME/Library/Application Support/Code[ -
  Variant]/User/workspaceStorage/
- Linux : $HOME/.config/Code[ - Variant]/User/workspaceStorage/

could refer to [add jar](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_standalone-java-file-support)

Comment: Thanks! I found also that to clean the workspace, you can press F1 and select 'Java:Clean the …' from the menu. Also, one post suggested adding 'exported="true"' to the three classpathentry elements, before 'kind="lib". Once I got past this issue, there were other issues. Mostly I fixed those with edits to launch.json osx and windows entries so that once I compiled my .class file, the runtime could find the needed log4j jar files. Thanks again!