# Jar in classpath not recognized

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code does not include either servlet-api.jar or mssql-jdbc-7.0.0.jre8.jar, no matter where I put it.

I have put it in the lib directory of the jdk, jre, and local to the code(src directory).

Comment: How did you specify your classpath?

Comment: Created a Java Project and added it to .classpath file - it would show in Java Dependencies but would not expand or show in completion or add import

Comment: Also added the tomcat server which includes the servlet-api.jar in it's lib.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the jar in the right way ?

you could refer to this issue :https://stackoverflow.com/a/56053944/10768653

and you could look at the doucument [add jar](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_standalone-java-file-support)