# Add current project to vscode launch.json "classpaths" field

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, classpath

I'm trying to debug my Java project in vscode. I added a launch.json file that looks like this:

```
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "java",
      "name": "Debug with args",
      "args": "--args_for_app",
      "classPaths": ["$HOME/bin/some.jar", "$HOME/bin/some_other.jar"],
      "env": {
        "env1": "env1value"
      },
      "request": "launch",
      "mainClass": "my.main.ClassName",
      "projectName": "projectName",
      "console": "internalConsole"
    }
  ]
```

If I remove the `classPaths` field, vscode automatically resolves the current project into the classpath, and the debugger starts successfully, but I need to also add other jar files into classpath. If I add the field with my desired jar paths, vscode no longer resolves the project's path automatically (which makes sense), but now I don't know how to add it back to the list.

I tried adding `"."`, `"${file}"`, and `"${workspace}"`, none worked. I still get an error saying the main class can't be found:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class my.main.ClassName
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.main.ClassName
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the main problem is to add jar as the dependency, right? Please have a look at the official doc:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_standalone-java-file-support

A function has been added to specify the jar files as the library.

---

Here is the edit, we can do the following to add jars/lib in VSCode:

1. Add your .jar file into a `./lib` in your project root.
2. Configure paths in the .classpath to point to your jars, like:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/my.jar"/>
```

3. If the jars are not picked up, clean the workspace directory. You can do this by running the "Clean the Java language server workspace" command. You can also manually clean the workspace directories:

The VS Code user workspace storage area can be found under these locations :

Windows : %APPDATA%\Code[ - Variant]\User\workspaceStorage\

MacOS : $HOME/Library/Application Support/Code[ - Variant]/User/workspaceStorage/

Linux : $HOME/.config/Code[ - Variant]/User/workspaceStorage/
could refer to add jar

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for my project, it's not a standalone file. :)

Comment: Actually I haven't heard such a way can that can add multiple files use a single line of setting. Even in marven it's a file which add jar package one by one. Do you mean you have lots of files and in this way manually do it is not reasonable?

Comment: No I mean having a `./lib` directory with two jar files in it doesn't seem to add them to the classpath. I have to explicitly add the `"classPaths": ["one.jar", "two.jar"]` field in `launch.json`.

Comment: Can you make sure you've tried to add to .classpath file by follow my colleage Leo's workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56044133/vscodejavawindows-i-want-to-import-and-use-org-apache-logging-log4j-logger-wi/56053944#56053944

Comment: Ah, that worked! Can you please update the answer so I can accept it?
Also, can this be added to the doc page you linked? I wasn't aware of the .classpath before your comment.

Comment: @yelsayed I will push the update from the doc from our internal channel. Looks like last time when we pushed the update for the doc, the content about .classpath is not updated to the doc.