# log4j + Visual Studio Code: Is it possible to integrate log4j for test automation in VS Code?

Tags: java, selenium, visual-studio-code, log4j

I am a newbie in test automation. I am trying to create a framework for learning using java, maven, testNG. So far I was able to run testcases and I follow POM method. But now I have a problem in integrating log4j for test automation logs in VS code. I am getting following error:

```
Logger cannot be resolved to a typeJava(16777218)
```

I have log4j added to my maven dependency

```
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
```

And added

```
public static Logger logger;
...
logger=Logger.getLogger("xyz");
PropertyConfigurator.configure("Log4j.properties");
```

But this is not working. So if anyone has configured log4j in VS code please share how it is done. Or please let me know any other method to log in VS code.

Comment: yes, same issue, for me the  project don't found the package org.apache.logging.log4j.*

Comment: see this link to solve : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56044133/vscodejavawindows-i-want-to-import-and-use-org-apache-logging-log4j-logger-wi

Answer (score 0):

Import necessary  dependencies of log4j --> Add log4j.properties in main/resources (if you don't have it then create it) --> run your code.

If you are using log4j2(version >=2.4) then use log4j2 in above steps.